# Calcular la URL base me funciona en localhost pero no en un servidor

Tags: javascript

He realizado una pequeña aplicación con PHP y `$.ajax()`.

Para no estar buscando las rutas relativas a cada rato he capturado la URL base usando el siguiente código:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin + "/" + location.pathname.split("/")[1];
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: base_url + "/funciones/ajax.php",
       data: new FormData(this), 
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
       cache: false,
       success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data)},
      });
```

En localhost funciona correctamente, pero al momento de subirlo a un servidor deja de funcionar.

Según estaba viendo al momento de querer enviar los datos la URL no es reconocida. Pero no entiendo por qué si en localhost trabaja bien.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

---

*Edición extraída desde los comentarios:*

Si hago un `console.log()` en local me muestra `localhost/mi-proyecto/inicio` y en el servidor `dominio/inicio`.

Si en URL del `$.ajax` coloco: `dominio/functions/ajax.php` funciona, pero si lo dejo `base_url + "/funciones/ajax.php"` no funciona.

---

*Actualización: estructura de directorios*

```
Raíz del documento
├─ assets/
│   ├─ css/
│   └─ js/
├─ functions/
│   └─ ajax.php
├─ index.php
└─ inicio.php
```

Comment: no será : ` base_url + "/ajax.php"`  ????

Comment: si tienes razon lo siento me falto colocarlo, pero igual ese no es el problema.

Comment: y si colocas un console.log(base_url ) en la 2da línea, que aparece ?? y cual sería la url  correcta?

Comment: bueno asi tal como esta si hago un console.log() en local me muestra: http://localhost/mi-proyecto/inicio y en el servidor https://dominio/inicio. Si en url del ajax coloco: https://dominio/functions/ajax.php funciona. Pero si lo dejo base_url + "/funciones/ajax.php" no funciona

Comment: Entonces tú dices que en localhost funciona "localhost/inicio/functions/ajax.php" y en el servidor "dominio/functions/ajax/.php" y supongo que las carpetas están igual en ambos lados!!!! Puede ser que tengas una regla en el ` .htaccess.` ?

Comment: En todo caso, si no te quieres calentar la cabeza, puedes hacer algo como `let index = location.host == "localhost" ? 1 :  0; let base_url = window.location.origin + "/" + location.pathname.split("/")[index];`

Answer (score 2):

Tu código JavaScript para evitar usar rutas relativas no funciona de manera adecuada, sobre todo cuando agregas o quitas un nivel de directorios en el nuevo servidor.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo:

```js
const localización1 = new URL(
  "http://localhost/mi-proyecto/inicio/pagina.php"
);
console.log(
  localización1.origin + "/"
  + localización1.pathname.split("/")[1]
);

const localización2 = new URL(
  "http://www.pagina.com/inicio/pagina.php"
);
console.log(
  localización2.origin + "/"
  + localización2.pathname.split("/")[1]
);
```

Por mucho que te disgusten o trates de evitar el uso de rutas relativas, es la alternativa más sencilla que te permite mover tu código de un dominio a otro y de un directorio base a otro sin que su funcionamiento falle.

Así que te recomiendo que uses este código para acceder al subdirectorio donde está el archivo `ajax.php` de manera transportable:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "functions/ajax.php",
    data: new FormData(this),
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tal fue? Deberías editar la pregunta y compartir la estructura de directorios para poder localizar adecuadamente los archivos mediante rutas relativas.

Comment: Aun no lo pruebo aunque no me queda del todo claro como usarlos. Eh editado la pregunta agregando mas o menos como esta estrucuradas las carpetas. De inicio.php envia el ajax a ajax.php ¿como llego a esa ruta con el ejemplo que me proporcionaste?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta para cambiar la ruta relativa de acuerdo con el esquema que has presentado en la pregunta. PD: En la edición anterior cometí una errata con el nombre del directorio donde se aloja el guión `ajax.php`. Ya está corregido.